# Graphic card performance impact on baking light

Tags: baking, performance

This question might be a bit of topic but currently im using a computer with a Geforce GTX 1060 6GB graphics card.

Baking the lights of certain meshes with 10k samples can take up to 8-10 hours for me.

Does any one of you guys know how much "Baking-time" can be reduced by upgrading the computer and graphic card to a GeForce RTX 3060 12GB or Geforce 3070 8GB?

Answer (score 2):

10k sampling is a very bad idea, you will have to use a lower value and find the sweet spot for your render. A RTX graphics card could be used for denoising with OptiX, it's build into blender. But do not sample with 10k, the best RTX card won't be able to render magically in some minutes with this sampling value.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8gSyEpt4-60&t=37s helped me a lot

Comment: I'm using the bake-tool add-on and the higher the samples the more "clean" the lightmaps look. So why would less samples be bad practice?

And thanks for the YouTube link, will look into that!

Comment: Watch the video, chapter 5 and 6 will give you an answer. As mentioned 10k sampling is to high. Also the tile size could save you some render time.